# Not able to import specific excel cell to a texbox: Object reference not set to an instance of an object thrown C#

Tags: c#

Hi I am trying to import value of a specific excel cell to a textbox on the form. The value will appear as soon as the form loads. Now this cell can be null and I am taking care of the null value but it is throwing an exception and going into catch everytime a null value is passed. Here is the snippet of my code:

```
try
{
    var v;
    if( oSheet.Cells[3, 4].Value2 != null)
    {
        v = Sheet.Cells[3, 4].Value2; 
        var s = Convert.ToString(v);
        textBox1 = string.Format("{0:N2}", s);
    } 
    else 
    { 
        v = 0;
        var s = Convert.ToString(v);
        textBox1 = string.Format("{0:N2}", v);
    } 
}
catch(Exception)   
{
    string errorMessage = "Data cannot be retrieved from the strats file ;
    MessageBox.Show(errorMessage);
}
```

The catch is showing this exception "object reference not set to an instance of an object". I am taking care or the null oSheet.Range.Value2, then why is it throwing error as soon as it reaches the if statement ? Can someone please help I am frustrated with this problem since quite few days

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialize the "oSheet" object?

```
if( oSheet.Cells[3, 4].Value2 != null)
{
//I think you have a spelling mistake,    oSheet.Cells[3, 4] vs Sheet.Cells[3,4] 
    v = Sheet.Cells[3, 4].Value2; 
....
}
```

Comment: umm... I haven't... how do you initialize osheet I mean it is not a variable or something?... Yeah I noticed the spelling mistake but that has been taken care of. You mean while defining I should define oSheet like this  `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet oSheet = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet;`  and not like this `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet oSheet;` ?

Comment: What is the type of osheet?

Comment: I think you have to read the excel into a workbook first, then initialize using"Worksheet osheet =(worksheet) workbook.sheets[i]", you can get more instruction from [Excel guide](http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel) and [Microsoft workbook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms282308%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: I will show you the whole code so that it is more clearer:'
`namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form5 frm1;Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook oWB;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet oSheet;
  oSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)oWB.Worksheets["Dashboard"];`

Comment: Here is my working code : Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();

            string workbookPath = "C:/Book1.xlsx";
            Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath,
                    0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "",
                    true, false, 0, true, false, false);
            Excel.Sheets excelSheets = excelWorkbook.Worksheets;//I cannot replicate your problem with the null value osheet.

Comment: Another thing I want to suggest is doublecheck your worksheet name "Worksheets["Dashboard"];"